# Working with Aura's OMI data in ENVI

Tags: envi

I have downloaded Aura's Ozone Monitoring Instrument (OMI) data from http://mirador.gsfc.nasa.gov website but I can not work with them. How can I open these data in ENVI and what pre-processes are needed for these images?

Answer (score 1):

You can download Panoply software and use it to analyze OMI data.

https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/download/